# Update current WP post every 3 minutes

Tags: save-post

I wish to auto update/publish the changes of a post I am editing every 3 minutes. Any idea how can I achieve that?

Comment: So instead of auto-saving to a draft, you want to explicitly publish the post at intervals?

Comment: Yes. I figured it out for both gutenberg and classic editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Classic Editor:**

autosave.js file

```js
setInterval(function () {document.getElementById("publish").click()}, 300000);
```

php function

```
// Load js file on specific post type in class editor
function load_js_file_classic_editor( $hook ) {

    global $post;

    if ( $hook == 'post-new.php' || $hook == 'post.php' ) {
        if ( 'post' === $post->post_type ) {     
            wp_enqueue_script(  'myautosave', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/includes/js/autosave.js' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js_file_classic_editor', 10, 1 );
```

**Gutenberg**

```js
setInterval(function() {
    wp.data.dispatch( 'core/editor' ).savePost();
}, 60 * 1000); // 60 * 1000 milsec
```